# Getting "U" on my outputs forever

Tags: output, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I'm new to VHDL and today is my deadline to submit my project to the professor, so please be patient with me haha. I've written this code, it multiplies two 4-bit unsigned numbers and uses an 8-bit full-adder to do so (it was requested by the professor). Here's my source code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Atividade2 is
port(a,b: in std_logic_vector(0 to 7); clk,rst: in std_logic; prod: out std_logic_vector(0 to 7) := "00000000");
end Atividade2; 
architecture Behavioral of Atividade2 is

component somador_8bit
port(a,b: in std_logic_vector(0 to 7); ci: in std_logic; soma: out std_logic_vector(0 to 7); co: out std_logic);
end component;

signal result: std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
signal reg2: std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
signal reg3: integer range 0 to 15;
signal reg4: std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
signal cont: integer range 0 to 15 := 0;

begin

SOMA: somador_8bit port map(reg2,a,'0',result,open);
reg4 <= b;
process(clk)
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
reg3 <= to_integer(unsigned(reg4));
if(cont < reg3) then
reg2 <= result;
cont <= cont + 1;
end if;
end if;

end process;
prod <= result;

end Behavioral;
```

Here's the test bench code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_TEXTIO.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
USE STD.TEXTIO.ALL;

ENTITY atv2wf IS
END atv2wf;

ARCHITECTURE testbench_arch OF atv2wf IS
FILE RESULTS: TEXT OPEN WRITE_MODE IS "results.txt";

COMPONENT Atividade2
    PORT (
        a : In std_logic_vector (0 To 7);
        b : In std_logic_vector (0 To 7);
        clk : In std_logic;
        rst : In std_logic;
        prod : Out std_logic_vector (0 To 7)
    );
END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL a : std_logic_vector (0 To 7) := "00000000";
SIGNAL b : std_logic_vector (0 To 7) := "00000000";
SIGNAL clk : std_logic := '0';
SIGNAL rst : std_logic := '0';
SIGNAL prod : std_logic_vector (0 To 7) := "00000000";

constant PERIOD : time := 20 us;
constant DUTY_CYCLE : real := 0.5;
constant OFFSET : time := 100 us;

BEGIN
    UUT : Atividade2
    PORT MAP (
        a => a,
        b => b,
        clk => clk,
        rst => rst,
        prod => prod
    );

    PROCESS    -- clock process for clk
    BEGIN
        WAIT for OFFSET;
        CLOCK_LOOP : LOOP
            clk <= '0';
            WAIT FOR (PERIOD - (PERIOD * DUTY_CYCLE));
            clk <= '1';
            WAIT FOR (PERIOD * DUTY_CYCLE);
        END LOOP CLOCK_LOOP;
    END PROCESS;

    PROCESS
        BEGIN
            -- -------------  Current Time:  109us
            WAIT FOR 109 us;
            rst <= '1';
            a <= "00000111";
            b <= "00000010";
            -- -------------------------------------
            -- -------------  Current Time:  129us
            WAIT FOR 20 us;
            rst <= '0';
            -- -------------------------------------
            WAIT FOR 891 us;

        END PROCESS;

END testbench_arch;
```

Here's my RTL View. Everything seems to be setup and wired fine, RTL circuit seems to be ok, but all I'm getting is "U" on the ***prod*** output. Can anyone PLEASE save meee??
[RTL View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTmTv.jpg)

Comment: Your RTL View schematic isn't very informative, but appears to show the `prod output as the FDE register input. What happens if that register is never cleared (and contains all 'U's)? rst is not shown as used. Your question is lacking a bit of detail there, and a schematic isn't VHDL.

Comment: Your question isn't a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your result can't be duplicated. (Kudos for providing the testbench).

Comment: The issue is likely in `somador_8bit`, but that's the code you don't show...

Comment: Thanks guys. I tested somador_8bit separatedly from The others and It seems to work Just Fine, adding A(0:7) and B(0:7). Didn't understand what you mean user1155120. Prod is receiving OUTPUT of somador_8bit as input, and feedbacking to The input of somador_8bit again to perform The sum again, and again, until counter reaches value of input B.

Comment: What he and I are saying: you are not providing all the code, so we cannot easily reproduce your issue. Click his link for an explination.